# How to add a policy for role in ASP.NET Core for JWT?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I know that I can add a policy for my JWT custom claim this way:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("HasRole", policy => policy.RequireClaim("role", "Teacher"));
    });
```

However, my JWT token has an array of roles:

```
// parsed jwt token
{
   ...,
   roles: ['Teacher', 'Parent', 'Admin']
   ...
}
```

And I don't know how to rewrite the above code:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("IsTeacher", 
                 policy => policy.RequireClaim("roles", /*what should I write here*/));
    });
```

How can I require an item of an array in `RequireClaim`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your policies according to your roles with *RequireRole()*:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(o =>
{
    // Teacher or admin can access.
    o.AddPolicy("RequireTeacherRole", p => p.RequireRole("teacher", "admin"));
    // Only admin can access.
    o.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", p => p.RequireRole("admin"));
});
```

Now you can protect your MVC/API controllers or razor pages

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "RequireTeacherRole")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Where `RequireRole` reads its data from? Those claims are custom claims. What if the name of my claim is `kdkksk`? How .NET Core extracts roles from custom claism?

Comment: I think RequireClaim follows the same rule: `p => p.RequireClaim("kdkksk", "teacher", "admin")`

ASP.NET handles this by checking if any of the supported values in this claim matches any of the specified values:
`context.User.Claims.Any(c => string.Equals(c.Type, requirement.ClaimType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && requirement.AllowedValues.Contains(c.Value, StringComparer.Ordinal));` (see https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement.cs,6358046ecd2af5b7,references)

Comment: That's for when you pass multiple values to `RequireClaim`. For example `RequireClaim("role", "admin", "teacher")`. But my situation is different. I only want to include one role. `RequireClaim("role", "Teacher")`. However, the role is specified in a custom jwt claim with an array as its value.